# Kotlin/Java: should this singleton object have these sub-methods to check?

Tags: java, oop, kotlin, design-patterns

I have a singleton object, call it `Bank`. `Bank` has several methods, like `addCustomer`, `addRent`, etc. Each method has some parameters to do the job. 
However, the precondition is that, some methods require me to check if that object, given by the parameter, exist, or does not exists (for example: when `addCustomer`, check if `customerID` is already in the database). So my class `Bank` looks like this, let's simplify it.

```java
object Bank{
   //Some lists to store data here

   fun addCustomer(customerID: String){
   checkIfCustomerExist(customerID)
   // Do something here
   }

   private fun checkIfCustomerExist(customerID: String){
   // If customer is in list, throw exception
   }
}
```

So far so good.
However, my program has many lists and required functions, so it has a ***lot*** of utilities methods to check if exist/not exist. Is it ok, or what should I do to follow the design principles? I plan to create another singleton object Verification and implement all these check methods there. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The answer is "it depends". One option is to have a class for custumerId `CustomerID` which ensures that it is referring to a valid customer and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dependency injection which is suggested design principle instead of having many object class. I personally user Dagger2 currently. object/singleton is waste of resources if there are many objects. Dependency injection also enables testable code. But, if you have few object classes and you think they are not waste of resource, then it should be ok.

```
@MyCustomizedScope
class Bank
@Inject
constructor(
// here any number of variables can come
val bankId: Int // bankId is unique over the existence of Bank class 
){
     // todo
}
```

In the example **@MyCustomizedScope** is used to define existence period of the Bank class. For example in android, @MyCustomizedScope could be bound to main screen where this class lives. In this case, it only lives as long as the screen exists. But if you declare it as an **object** the class exists until application dies which is unnecessary.

So, It is recommended to use dependency injection.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved if you had some code to show how dependency injection helps with the OPs problem. Doesn't need to include a specific framework, just constructor injection would be enough

Comment: Thank you matt freake for you help;)